# UFW: Forward port to another IP on the same interface/subnet

Tags: ufw, port-forwarding

I need to forward port X to another IP within subnet. There's an [answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/607692/18079) that is exactly what I need, however, UFW documentation states:

```
# Uncomment this to allow this host to route packets between interfaces
#net/ipv4/ip_forward=1
```

The comment caught my attention in regards to interfaces. What if my machine has only one interface? Do I still need to enable IP forwarding, or there's another way how can I achieve this on the same interface?

Please note, I'm using ufw, and would like to stick to that if possible.